chcp doesn't work when called from inside 'for /f' loop
I have a script to convert from 1251 code page (ansi) to 866 code page (oem).
It takes content of file 'ansi.txt', converts it and then saves to 'oem.txt'
@echo off

chcp 1251
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ansi.txt) do (
  call :f_chcp 866
  echo %%a >>oem.txt
  call :f_chcp 1251
)
exit /b

:f_chcp
chcp %1 >nul
exit /b

It works well.
But if I replace "call :f_chcp 866" with just "chcp 866 >nul" it doesn't. In that case it outputs to file using previous value of code page (1251).
Can anyone explain why? Chcp.com is external binary. How is it possible that when it called from inside 'for /f' loop it does no desired effect. However, chcp then still reports that code page has been changed. And what has changed when it called from inside the same loop but being wrapped in subroutine?

I do not know the answer now. I suppose, the batch context is the cause. The entire for loop is already loaded into the internal command queue with the batch context as defined on parsing the FOR loop. Each execution of the command call forces the creation of a new batch context on which cmd.exe takes over the current setting for the input and output character encoding (code page) for the commands to execute next for reading bytes from a text file and interpreting them as characters and writing characters as bytes to a text file.

The execution of a program like chcp.com does not change the batch context. Well, this is the only executable which changes something on batch context at all. cmd.exe obviously does not check after every execution of a command during running commands loaded already into a command queue if the code page for input and/or output stream changed after the command execution and the other commands in the command queue must be executed therefore in a new context with a changed character encoding. But that is just a supposition.

I think, cmd.exe checks for a change of the code page only between a batch file close and the next open of the batch file for parsing the next lines. The entire FOR loop without call is read once from the batch file. Then the batch file is closed and cmd.exe runs the FOR loop with the commands already loaded into the internal command queue. After the execution of the FOR loop without call finished, cmd.exe needs to open the batch file again and recognizes now a code page change before reading the bytes of the batch file and interpreting them as text with current code page

The usage of call inside the FOR loop forces cmd.exe to open the batch file multiple times and reading and parsing lines from the batch file. That is most likely the reason why cmd.exe recognizes the change of the code page for input and output stream on using call inside the FOR loop. See also: How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts? and Why is a GOTO loop much slower than a FOR loop and depends additionally on power supply?

Three off topic hints: 1. There should be used %SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com (fully qualified file name) in the batch file instead of just chcp as otherwise cmd.exe must do a lot of file system accesses during the batch file execution for finding this executable using the environment variables PATH and PATHEXT again and again. 2. echo %%a >>oem.txt should be changed to >>oem.txt echo(%%a to write the OEM encoded text without a trailing space into the file oem.txt on no trailing space at the end of this line in the batch file.

3. Replacing "tokens=*" by delims^=^ eol^= for the definition of an empty list of delimiters to turn off the default line splitting behavior and not anymore removing leading spaces/tabs as with "tokens=*" on processing lines from ansi.txt and the definition of no end of line character to process also lines beginning with a semicolon (after 0 or more spaces/tabs) could be useful to process really the lines in ansi.txt as stored in this file with exception of empty lines which FOR always ignores and which cannot be turned off. echo( is used to output all lines correct.

It's just the call!
It works even with a call to an empty function
@echo off

chcp 1251
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ansi.txt) do (
  chcp 866
  call :activate_chcp_effect
  (echo %%a) >>oem.txt
  chcp 1251
)
exit /b

:activate_chcp_effect
exit /b

And it seems superfluous to switch between code pages in every loop.
This code snippet only changes the code page in the first loop, and the output file is only opened once.
This should be much faster.
set "cp_active="
chcp 1251 > NUL
(
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (ansi.txt) do (
    if not defined cp_active (
      set "cp_active=1"
      chcp 866 > NUL
      call :sub
    )
    (echo(%%a)
  )
) >oem.txt
chcp 1251 > NUL


Amazing! Yes, it's just the call. And yes, with your approach it much faster. Thank you!
